# Azure Automation Job Output

Tags: azure-automation

I was under the impression that `Get-AzureRmAutomationJobOutputRecord` would create an object that includes the full, non-truncated job output. Could anybody let me know how I get the non-truncated output of the 'summary' attribute? No matter what I try the output is always truncated.

Comment: Yes, that is what Get-AzureRmAutomationJobOutputRecord is for. Can you add more details on what Get-AzureRmAutomationJobOutputRecord returns for you? Are you able to see the data you are trying to see in full, in full in the Automation portal experience?

Comment: Below is what I get, only part of what I see in portal:  
6951ceee-44c5-47f8-86a3-279ce7d8ed82:[localhost]:PAT0017-SccmConfiguration: SCCM...
6951ceee-44c5-47f8-86a3-279ce7d8ed82:[localhost]:SOL0001:WindowsStorageConfigura...

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the portal view of this same output (which shows all the output correctly), and the cmdlet code you used that gave you incorrect, truncated output.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, was looking at wrong property. Details are not in 'summary' but 'value'. Thanks for pointing this out Joe.

```
Get-AzureRmAutomationJob -AutomationAccountName AzureAutomation -ResourceGroupName RgName | 
Sort-Object -Property LastModifiedTime | Select-Object -Last 1 | 
Get-AzureRmAutomationJobOutput |
Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.Summary -like '*PAT0*') -or ($_.Summary -like '*SOL0*')} |
Get-AzureRmAutomationJobOutputRecord | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```